# php variable as parameter to function on onclick

Tags: php, function, onclick

i have this code:

```
 <div class="item" onclick="function('; <?php  print_r(utf8_encode($variables["ID"])) ;  ?>')">
```

Basically, i want to pass to the function the value on variables ID but i tried many ways and it doessn't work (not this one or the other). Is always the problem with '' and the echo of the php.

Comment: wirte the function name the keyword `function` cannot be used as name

Comment: it was just an example:)

Comment: ok.. then try echo instead of `print_r();` as given in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why `;` inside the function argument? Remove it. Try with -

```
<div class="item" onclick="function xyz('<?php  echo utf8_encode($variables["ID"]);?>')">
```

You should add some function name.

Comment: Thanks, it works. i didn't saw that ";" there.I just was always altering that i must put it there by error